# How to scale text when drawing to an Image with c#

Tags: c#, text, scale, system.drawing

I would like to draw some text in a rectangle and have it scale to the maximum size that fits within the rectangle.

So far I have this:

```
    Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(500, 500);
    Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImage); 
    graphicImage.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);

    graphicImage.DrawString( "testing testing 123!", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, rect);               
    bitmapImage.Save("test.png");
```

it draws the text but doesn't scale up the font size.

Comment: No sign of Graphics.ScaleTransform() in your snippet.  Finding the right arguments to pass to it is the // todo comment.  Measure the string.

Answer (score 1):

Call Graphics.MeasureString in a binary search loop.

Comment: Ouch, I was hoping for something in the .net framework instead of having to do it manually.

Comment: Hans mentioned ScaleTransform, in that case, draw the string once, measure it, then scale it, much simpler.